# Error with Xcode in mac "file doesn't exist" error

Tags: macos, ibm-mobilefirst

I am working with Eclipse, mobilefirst 7 dev server, Xcode in mac. My project build and deploying is successful but its not running in Xcode and I am getting **file doesn't exist** error. I don't know where can I change the path or any corrections.

Here is the error message:

```
[2015-05-11 09:48:35]             Resource conf/jndi/default.properties not found. This is not an error. Context path is / 
[2015-05-11 09:48:35]             Resource conf/jndi/default.properties not found. This is not an error. Context path is __globalscope__ 
[2015-05-11 09:50:19]             Starting build process: application 'MobileMOT', environment 'iphone' 
[2015-05-11 09:50:24]             Application 'MobileMOT' with environment 'iphone' build finished.
[2015-05-11 09:50:24]             Deploying application 'MobileMOT' with environment 'iphone' to MobileFirst Server... 
[2015-05-11 09:50:27]             Application 'MobileMOT' deployed successfully with environment 'iphone'
[2015-05-11 09:50:27]             Error: The files /Users/munna/Desktop/mot and /Users/munna/Desktop/spt files/mac softwares/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/files/Mobile_MOT/apps/MobileMOT/iphone/native/MobileMOTMobileMOTphone.xcodeproj 
do not exist.. Error number (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have spaces in the path: "spt files/ mac softwares".
Change the folder names so that there will not be any spaces and try again.